# Ehrenfest Model in R:

Tags: r, simulation, mean, median, variance

There are two urns, one (urn A) empty and the other (B urn) containing n balls. Continuing to draw balls randomly, according to the Ehrenfest model, sooner or later the urn B will be emptied completely and all n balls in the urn will be passed to urn A.

The function Ehr is:

```
    Ehr <- function(n)
{
    A <- numeric(0)
    B <- c(1:n)
    nest <- 0
repeat {
    out <- sample(c(A,B),size=1)
    nest <- nest + 1
    ris <- intersect(out,A)
    if (length(ris)==1) {
       A <- setdiff(A,out); B <- c(B,out) }
    else {
       B <- setdiff(B,out); A <- c(A,out)
    }
    if (length(A)==n) break
}
    return(nest)
}
```

It returns the number k of extractions performed (in a single simulation) to pass completely n balls from the urn urn B to A.

**I have to calculate the case where there are initially 2 balls in the urn B. By repeating the simulation 1000 times (ie calling the function Ehr 1000 times), calculate the mean of k, the median of k, the variance of k, the interquartile range of k.**

Someone can help me?

This is an example with initially 3 balls in the urn B.

> Set.seed (123456) for (i in 1:5) cat (Ehr (3), "") cat ("\ n")
>   13 3 11 5 7 #possible observed values

Answer (score 0):

```
dd=sapply(rep(2,10000),Ehr)
customSummary = function(x) { paste("Mean:",mean(x),"Median:",median(x),"Variance:",var(x),"IQR:",diff(quantile(x,probs=c(0.25,0.75)))) }
customSummary(dd)
```

just repeat and display your code